# Installing a windows application through web page

Tags: asp.net, windows, installation

How can I install a windows application through web paged "Like installing yahoo messenger"?

Answer (score 3):

It used to be:

```
<object type="application/x-oleobject"
    classid="(classid of an activex control your app installs to mark that it is present)"
    codebase="http://www.example.com/your/install.cab"
>
    Install my grate program pls
</object>
```

But it's not worth bothering do this any more, the user has to go through the ‘information bar’ at the top to even allow it to prompt you to install something, and if it doesn't work due to any number of permissions/settings problems it's a dead end.

There are other methods of various levels of browser-specificity, such as Firefox's SecurityManager, or Java signed jars but they're pretty much a waste of time.

Just link to a simple .exe and everyone's happy. I don't know about where you are, but for me going to the ‘download Yahoo Messenger’ page just gives me a plain old:

```
<a href="http://rd.software.yahoo.com/msgr/9/msgr9us.exe">Download Now</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to simply provide a link to an installer, you should also consider [ClickOnce](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/30460). This allows installing and running to a sandboxed user account, and updating old versions, from a web page with a single click.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dour High Arch, ClickOnce is your best bet

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will usually stop this because of the obvious security risk.
On Windows, the various resulting warnings (XP onwards) can be made more benign looking by signing with an Authenticode certificate (you are doing that, right?).